# Python and pubsubhubbub

Tags: python, websub

I wrote a quick http server script to first acknowledge a subscription and receive updates. I was able to verify the subscription and start receiving updates. With this method I'm able to print the updated feed items to the console but google's subscriber diagnostics says the receipt failed.

Shouldn't this be enough?:
(this is inside a handler class subclassed with BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler)

```
def do_POST(self):
    self.send_response(202)
    self.end_headers()
    stuff = self.rfile.read()
    print stuff
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems with status code 204 it's fine. I guess because I have no body in the response? Anyway, working fine now.

I'd be greatful to get a comment if someone knows why I needed that particular status code. The spec just says 2xx.